# C - How to read certain lines from a file? ( Not all lines or entire file but just certain lines)

Tags: c, file

I tried looking for similar questions that could find an answer to my question but i couldn't seem to find it. Could someone please tell me is there any way to read certain lines from the .txt file. For example i would like to read lines 2,3,5 from the text file.

Example of text file:

```
1255466889436     //Line 1 - I want to read this line
5489784642165     //Line 2
4984651425165     //Line 3 - I want to read this line
4968164816514     //Line 4
4161654168468     //Line 5 - I want to read this line
```

It would be nice if somone could show example code cause im really stumped at the moment.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Easiest way would be to read line by line with a counter incrementing per line, and just discard the even number lines.

Comment: You will have to read all lines and skip the ones you don't want. I don't think there's any OS which has a way to read files by lines.

Comment: You have to set up a line counter variable, read each line, and discard the ones you don't want as you go.

Comment: 2,3,5 or 1,3,5?  All the odd lines or a specific mask of lines described by a list of line numbers?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207550/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-go-to-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: This question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504096/how-to-read-in-a-specific-line-from-an-input-file-in-c. It at least has the code you need to do what you want with minor adjustment.

Comment: read from a positioning by `fseek` if fixed length.

Comment: Your file appears to be fixed-length records. Is this guaranteed to be true for all lines in the file?

Answer (score 2):

Read all lines, discard the ones you don't need.

You can seek to any offset in a file, but which line is offset 5000? That depends on how many newline characters there were in the previous 5000 characters. And unless you check all characters, you don't know.

Comment: All true, but if all the lines are exactly the same length (as shown in the question) then you *can* use fseek to extract selected lines without reading every line.

Comment: Perhaps you could optimize to keep track of the seek positions for some lines if the file is accessed as read-only and you have to access it more than once.

Comment: @user3386109: That's a POSIX thing. Windows has CR+LF translation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the lines and just ignore those that you do not need. Remember that you start from the beginning of the file and you keep reading the lines until you find those that you want or until the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this :
START READING FILE FROM FIRST CHARACTER TILL THE END OF FILE BY CHECKING  value of eof(),

Till End of file is reached(feof(fp)==0),

with the curent byte position as 0th byte or first byte of first line, we are reading the first line by fgets() till newline characte is reached. Once \n is reached, fgets() tops its function and the ead content is stored in data array. the string length in this aray is the total number of characters/bytes in first line. So adding 1 byte more than that, now the current byte position becomes the beginning byte of the next line.