# C - How to read in a certain line from a file

Tags: c, file, input, scanning

So I have a text file containing the following:

```
30.5 80.5 21
5
PERS Sarah 40 5 50
PERS Henry 30 10 20.6
PERS Martha 20 42 50.75
PERS John 35 10 80
PERS Jared 23 5 45.53
```

Without going into detail about what I need the program to do (I'll figure that out myself) 30.5 represents one price, 80.5 represents another price, and 21 represents a third price (all unique prices for different things)

The second line (the number 5) represents how many people are registering for a race.

The last 5 lines represent person information. PERS represents that an individual is registering, the name is obviously the person's name, the first number represents the person's age, the second number represents which race they're participating in (either a 5k run, 10k run, or 42k run) and the last number represents the amount of donations raised.

How can I scan a specific line of the file? For example, if I wanted to scan the information on John, how can I choose that I want to scan that line? It starts scanning from the first line of the file which I don't want. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: How can you know what you want to scan before you scan it? Wouldn't that mean you already had the string? If you're asking how to find a substring, the answer is that you can use `strstr`

Comment: How is the program suppored which line contains the entry for `John`? Once you can answer that, you should be able to write code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - How to read certain lines from a file? ( Not all lines or entire file but just certain lines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269628/c-how-to-read-certain-lines-from-a-file-not-all-lines-or-entire-file-but-ju)

Comment: You read each line, looking to see if it contains the information you want. There is no magic *please read only the line that contains something without reading the other lines first*, because code isn't capable of psychic behavior (knowing the content of a line before it reads the line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a way to just skip lines in a file - you'll just have to read it in starting from the first line. Plus you still need the information from the first lines anyway, right?

Comment: Ah, well if that's the case then I can probably write the code. I was messing around with some functions and thought of an easy way assuming this was possible. Thanks for the info!